# Position object in Scene Editor in Xcode 9 beta

Tags: xcode, ios11, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am new to SceneKit and not able to get a hold of the Xcode Scene Editor. I am doing some research on iOS ARKit which was introduced recently. I created a sample project with SceneKit template. It comes with a default **ship.scn**.

I deleted this ship.scn and created a new SCN, drag and dropped a sample **.DAE** model into this SCN. I am able to view the object that I placed in .SCN file clearly with all the textures.

But when I run it in the device, the object appears on top of camera and zoomed in and not positioning properly in the camera frame.
I had to give the position of the object as `x: 0`, `y: -60`, `z: -60` in Xcode Scene Editor to make it available in the center of the camera frame. But if I do this, the object will always be `-60` degree from camera and I will not be able to move/resize it correctly with touch gestures.

Anyone please help me on how to make the object available at the center of camera frame such that the object also supports rotation/resize/movement etc.

I created the scene like below and added it to scene view:

```
let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Lowpoly_Notebook_2.scn")!
```

I have used [Apple's link](https://developer.apple.com/sample-code/wwdc/2017/PlacingObjects.zip) as reference for moving/resizing objects.

Comment: How big is your model. One SceneKit unit in the Xcode editor is 1 meter when using ARKit. If your model is 100s of meters wide you are probably standing inside it and nothing gets rendered.

Comment: My model is not so big. Just a few meters. Is it possible to change the size of the model in scene editor?

Comment: You can change the scale of any node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [orangenkopf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5815048/orangenkopf) quoted, My problem was with the model size. It was huge and hence didn't get rendered properly. When i change the scale of the object in Xcode Scene editor to a minimum value, i am able to view the object correctly and place it anywhere needed.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is adding .dae file into the project and then `Editor -> convert to SceneKit scene file format (.scn)`.

Comment: I did convert my .dae file to .scn. But still having the same issue.

Comment: Can you change the position of this object? I think there are some issue with that. I'm trying to change the position and scale and nothing happens, I thing is a bug.

Comment: Same for me. I too tried changing the scaling and positioning in Xcode scene editor and nothing happens